how to ease the radius value along the bezier curve?
The radius pronunciation is linear. Is it possible to change it to something similar to orange curve in the image below. Can there be some easing control? Sorry my english is not perfect, I hope I used correct words...



Here is the solution, the formula comes from easing functions from the higgsas nodes.


